# Symfony Dependency Injection Component Standalone Inject Doctrine Entity Manager

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection, doctrine

I am developing a small application outside of the Symfony framework and I want to use the Symfony dependency injection component to automatically resolve my repositories which require `\Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager` as a parameter in their constructor.

I want to bind an existing instance to the dependency injection container - but I can't seem to figure this out from the documentation. It seems that the container is using reflection to get the class name of the instance and then create a new instance. The variable `$entityManager` is an instance of `\Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager`.

```
$container = new ContainerBuilder();
$container->register('doctrine.orm.entitymanager', $entityManager);
var_dump($container->get('doctrine.orm.entitymanager'));
```

The component throws a `ReflectionException` if I try to resolve the instance. What is the correct approach to this?

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'ReflectionException' with message 'Access to non-public constructor of class Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager' in /vagrant/sfs/vendor/symfony/dependency-injection/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/ContainerBuilder.php:955
Stack trace:
#0 /vagrant/sfs/vendor/symfony/dependency-injection/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/ContainerBuilder.php(955): ReflectionClass->newInstanceArgs(Array)
#1 /vagrant/sfs/vendor/symfony/dependency-injection/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/ContainerBuilder.php(488): Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder->createService(Object(Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Definition), 'doctrine.orm.en...')
#2 /vagrant/sfs/test.php(12): Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder->get('doctrine.orm.en...')
#3 {main}
  thrown in /vagrant/sfs/vendor/symfony/dependency-injection/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/ContainerBuilder.php on line 955

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'ReflectionException' with message 'Access to non-public constructor of class Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager' in /vagrant/sfs/vendor/symfony/dependency-injection/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/ContainerBuilder.php:955
Stack trace:
#0 /vagrant/sfs/vendor/symfony/dependency-injection/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/ContainerBuilder.php(955): ReflectionClass->newInstanceArgs(Array)
#1 /vagrant/sfs/vendor/symfony/dependency-injection/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/ContainerBuilder.php(488): Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder->createService(Object(Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Definition), 'doctrine.orm.en...')
#2 /vagrant/sfs/test.php(12): Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder->get('doctrine.orm.en...')
#3 {main}
  thrown in /vagrant/sfs/vendor/symfony/dependency-injection/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/ContainerBuilder.php on line 955
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you try to init the entity manager with the new command, this won't work.

```
new EntityManager();
```

You have to use the EntityManagerFactory.
https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineORMModule/blob/master/src/DoctrineORMModule/Service/EntityManagerFactory.php

But the EntityManager is in Symfony2 already registered as service

```
$container->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager');
```